# Android: Restrict TranslateAnimation on second time

Tags: android, listview, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm working on showing the image when list view item swipe. To achieve this i'm using helper class (Not the library)

**Helper class code**

*SwipeDetector*

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to Top
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    //private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

    public boolean swipeDetected() {
        return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return mSwipeDetected;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
            return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // horizontal swipe detection
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                if (deltaX < 0) {
                    //Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Left to Right");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                    return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    //Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                    return true;
                }
            } else 

                // vertical swipe detection
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        //Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Top to Bottom");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        //Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Bottom to Top");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                        return false;
                    }
                } 
            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

For this i hided the view in layout like `android:visibility="gone"` and i'm showing the image (View.VISIBLE) when user swiping from right to left (Fro understanding see this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView/master/demo.gif)) and hiding (View.GONE) it when swiping from left to right. For this hiding (View.GONE) i'm setting the animation like this

**Left to right swipe**

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,ivAdptDelete.getWidth(),0,0);
                        animate.setDuration(500);
                        animate.setFillAfter(true);
                        ivAdptDelete.startAnimation(animate);
                        ivAdptDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        Runnable buttonClickable = new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                ivAdptDelete.clearAnimation();
                            }
                        };

                        Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
                        pdCanceller.postDelayed(buttonClickable, 500);
```

**Right to left swipe**

```
ivAdptDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

For the first time when i'm swiping from left to right means nothing was showing because my view is hided (It was the correct process). If i swipe from Right to left and left to right everything fine. After completing this process if i swipe from left to right means the animation repeating again. My doubt is i hided view when swiping from left to right by `ivAdptDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);` but it again showing the animation when i'm swipe from left to right. So, any one give me the idea to restrict the animation when swiping from left to right for second time

Fode my code please check this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gnz5v0x0raet9p3/ListViewSwipeLeftRight.rar?dl=0)

Comment: When starting swipe, check getTranslationY() value.

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment